# Tidal effect on pressure at sea floor

Tags: gravity, tidal-effect

The tidal movement of water is explained by the gravitational changes due to the movement of earth, sun and moon.

So simply thought, sea water climbs higher in areas where the sum gravitation is lower in respect to other areas.

Does that mean that the pressure at sea floor does not change despite the amount of water above changes?

Comment: The height of the tides is the result of a resonant movement of all the water in the oceans in response to the weak gravitational tidal forces, so it's not directly proportional to the change in local gravity and locally it can produce a much higher tide.

Comment: So pressure would still change almost proportionally to the water depth?

Comment: Mass of the water (per unit area) overhead times the local gravitational constant, yes.